# Working with Canvec Data?

Tags: style, spatial-database, canada

I'm trying to join some downloaded CANVEC data to associated style file, but I am unable to join on the code field.

The field used to join the stylefile for ArcMap has been removed from the geometry, and updated with a new code, but the stylefile that comes with the data, has not been updated with the same code.

Would there be a simple solution, besides manually inputing the new code into the stylefile?